# C++ preprocessor removes whitespace in calls to variadic macros (Solaris Studio 12.3)

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, solaris, variadic-macros, solaris-studio

The C++ preprocessor of Oracle Solaris Studio 12.3 removes whitespace completely when expanding `__VA_ARGS__`.

Can anybody confirm this behaviour on their system? Is it a known compiler bug? Are there any workarounds for this problem?

To illustrate, here is a simple test program, `vaargs.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINT(...) printf("%s\n", #__VA_ARGS__)

int main()
{
    PRINT(hello world);

    return 0;
}
```

The C preprocessor works as expected:

```
$ cc vaargs.c -o vaargs && ./vaargs
hello world

$ cc -V
cc: Sun C 5.12 SunOS_i386 2011/11/16
```

But the C++ preprocessor removes the space between "hello" and "world":

```
$ CC vaargs.c -o vaargs && ./vaargs
helloworld

$ CC -V
CC: Sun C++ 5.12 SunOS_i386 2011/11/16
```

Comment: Both clang (3.5) and GCC (4.9.1) output `hello world` (for both C and C++) for me. I don't have Solaris Studio so I can't confirm with that.

Comment: It does appear to be an issue with the Solaris Studio 12.3 C++ preprocessor. The problem does not occur with the previous version (12.2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a compiler bug, as per [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 16.3.2 (cpp.stringize) p2 (the rest of the quote is snipped):

> A *character string literal* is a *string-literal* with no prefix. If, in the replacement 
>   list, a parameter is immediately preceded by a `#` preprocessing token, both are replaced 
>   by a single character string literal preprocessing token that contains the spelling of the 
>   preprocessing token sequence for the corresponding argument. Each occurrence of white space 
>   between the argument’s preprocessing tokens becomes a single space character in the 
>   character string literal.

Comment: Actually the removal of whitespace occurs before the stringize step, in the expansion of _\_VA_ARGS_\_.